# Sending a variable to discord channel Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, tweepy

So I have this code:

```
while True:
  recent_post = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'PartAlert', count = 1, since_id=recent_id, include_rts = True, tweet_mode='extended')
  if recent_post:
    last_post = recent_post[0].full_text
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', last_post)
    if urls:
      print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Link(s) Found:")
      for x in range(len(urls)):
        if urls[x][-1] == ':':
          urls[x] = urls[x][:-1]
        print(urls[x])
    recent_id = recent_post[0].id
  time.sleep(10)
```

which gets the twitter post of a specific user. What I want now is that the `url` variable will send  to a discord channel but whatever I try it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: And what exactly does "sending a variable to a discord channel" mean? Including it as a comment? Have you tried anything so far? The documentation for Python's wrappers of the Discord API is quite extensive, and sending messages to the channel is explained well there.

Comment: @KacperFloriański well I tried this `if urls[x][-1] == ':': urls[x] = urls[x][:-1] print(urls[x])
send_url(urls[x])`
and later on 
`def send_url(url):`
but it stands on  `send_url(urls[x])`
 Unresolved reference 'send_url'

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to place the `send_url` method **above** the line in which you call `send_url` (or you could use classes, but that might require redesigning your bot).

To send messages to a channel, you can use:

```
channel_id = # some channel id here
message = # some message here
channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
await channel.send(message)
```

You could also define `send_url` like so

```
async def send_url(channel_id, message):
    channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send(message)
```

Just be sure to place it **above** the line in which you call the method.